# Utility to convert List to Map

Tags: java

We can convert a list to map using the following

```
List<Item> list;
Map<Key,Item> map = new HashMap<Key,Item>();
for (Item i : list) {
  map.put(i.getKey(),i);
}
```

Is there is a java or apache common utility which does in a single line? Some times the key should be sequential integer, sometimes the key is the value itself (taking care of uniqueness).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) collector with a stream:

```
Map<Key, Item> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getKey, i -> i));
```